# Paypal SDK problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, paypal, sdk

Goodmornig,
I have some problems with the integration of SDK paypal, I have the IPN that works nice, now I was trying to do the first request, instead of the form client side, the call server side, to be more safe.
I have put in my bin folder Paypal.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll then I have configurated the web.config

This is what I have read when I downloaded the Paypal nuget from Visual.
ATTENTION: This package replaces the RestApiSDK package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/restapisdk). You do not need to include the RestApiSdk package in your project if you are using this, the PayPal .NET SDK, package.

The PayPal REST API uses HTTP verbs and a RESTful endpoint structure. OAuth2.0 is used as the API Authorization framework. Request and response payloads are formatted as JSON.

I usually dont use editor, I have downloaded Visual just to get out these dll.
Then I have copied them inside my Web ASP.NET application.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
</configSections>

<!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
<paypal>
    <settings>
        <add name="mode" value="live" />
        <add name="connectionTimeout" value="360000"/>
        <add name="requestRetries" value="1"/>
        <add name="clientId" value="xxx" />
        <add name="clientSecret" value="yyy" />
    </settings>
</paypal>
```

And then I have translated the c#.net script sample to vb.net, this is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" aspcompat=true%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PayPal.Api" %>

<%
       ' Initialize an APIContext object with a fresh access token.
        ' The config will be populated with values set in the Web.config file.
        Dim config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()
        Dim accessToken = New OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken()
        Dim apiContext = New APIContext(accessToken)
    Dim abc = Payment.Get(apiContext, "6N135681R73257100")
%>
```

I have put the ID of the transaction and I have this kind of error

PayPal.HttpException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

If I try to do a payment so to do like this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" aspcompat=true%>
<%@ Import Namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="PayPal.Api" %>

<%
       ' Initialize an APIContext object with a fresh access token.
        ' The config will be populated with values set in the Web.config file.
        Dim config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties()
        Dim accessToken = New OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken()
        Dim apiContext = New APIContext(accessToken)

        ' Initialize Payout object
        Dim payout = New Payout() With { _
        .sender_batch_header = New PayoutSenderBatchHeader() With { _
            .sender_batch_id = "batch_" + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), _
            .email_subject = "You have a payment" _
        }, _
        .items = New List(Of PayoutItem)({ _
            New PayoutItem() With { _
                .recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL, _
                .amount = New Currency() With { _
                .value = "0.99", _
                .currency = "USD" _
            }, _
            .receiver = "shirt-supplier-one@mail.com", _
            .note = "Thank you.", _
            .sender_item_id = "item_1" _
            }, _
            New PayoutItem() With { _
                .recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL, _
                .amount = New Currency() With { _
                .value = "0.90", _
                .currency = "USD" _
            }, _
                .receiver = "shirt-supplier-two@mail.com", _
                .note = "Thank you.", _
                .sender_item_id = "item_2" _
            }, _
            New PayoutItem() With { _
                .recipient_type = PayoutRecipientType.EMAIL, _
                .amount = New Currency() With { _
                .value = "2.00", _
                .currency = "USD" _
            }, _
                .receiver = "shirt-supplier-three@mail.com", _
                .note = "Thank you.", _
                .sender_item_id = "item_3" _
            } _
        }) _
        }

        ' Create the payout
        Dim createdPayout = payout.Create(apiContext, False)
%>
```

I have this kind of error, Did I forgot to copy inside my project anything? How could I fix it? Thank you very much

PayPal.HttpException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.